# How to get a Key name from a Javascript Object?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

Consider the below object and I'm trying to console the below-mentioned output.

```js
const jonas = {
  firstName: 'Jonas',
  lastName: 'Schmedtmann',
  age: 2037 - 1991,
  job: 'teacher',
  friends: ['Micheal', 'Peter', 'Steven']
};
console.log(`${jonas.firstName} has ${jonas.friends.length} friends, and his best friend is ${jonas.friends[0]}.`);
```

Now, instead of hardcoding friends in the console, how do I get the key name "friends" from the object?

Comment: You want to access `friends` property without using its name?

Comment: The `age`  value is incorrect, it should be wrapped in quotes because at best it's a string not a number nor is it a range of numbers (ex. array).

Comment: You could use a variable, ex. `let x = jonas.friends`. Although I don't see any real advantage in doing so.

Comment: Out of interest what's wrong with the way that you're currently doing it? What further problem are you trying to solve that isn't explained in your question?

Comment: `const { friends } = jonas; // do whatever needs to be done with 'friends'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following element

```
Object.keys(jonas)
```

that return an array of Keys of the object so you can take the value using

```
Object.keys(jonas)[4]
That return the key "friends"
```

Comment: ... which means you need to still know everything ... the data structure including the key names and their (insertion) precedence. So what is the advice good for?

Comment: You are right, 
I do not konw why he need to know programmatically print the key, value , but that can be a part for a more complex project, for example he can use it in a for each to get all infos like suggested in the below response. 
My response simply give a way to resolve its request.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a for loop:

```
const jonas = {
  firstName: 'Jonas',
  lastName: 'Schmedtmann',
  age: 2037 - 1991,
  job: 'teacher',
  friends: ['Micheal', 'Peter', 'Steven']
};

let hasFriends = false;

for (const key in jonas) {
if (key === 'friends') {
  hasFriends = true;
  break;
  }
}

if (hasFriends) {
  console.log(`${jonas.firstName} has ${jonas.friends.length} friends, and his 
best friend is ${jonas.friends[0]}.`);
} else {
  console.log(`${jonas.firstName} does not have any friends.`);
}
```

or even try:

```
for (const key in jonas) {
  console.log(`${key} has ${Array.isArray(jonas[key]) ? jonas[key].length : jonas[key]}.`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bracket Notation :

```
const jonas = {
    firstName: 'Jonas',
    lastName: 'Schmedtmann',
    age: 2037 - 1991,
    job: 'teacher',
    friends: ['Micheal', 'Peter', 'Steven']
};

const keyName = 'friends';
console.log(`${jonas.firstName} has ${jonas[keyName].length} ${keyName}, and his best ${keyName} is ${jonas[keyName][0]}.`);
```

Comment: The OP wants to use the property key from the object not another variable.

Comment: Yes. Could you please let me know the solution?